# Facebook API to download PDF invoices

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have found the [API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account/transactions/) to download transactions:

But there is no link to a PDF file of the actual invoice available. Does anyone knows if the actual PDF invoice can be downloaded using the API?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been deprecated with version 3.0 of Facebook API.

Answer (score -1):

I assume you need to obtain the PDFs as mentioned in https://www.facebook.com/business/help/117335431685396 .

But the API you point to will only provide with you with the JSON data of the related transactions. You can easily build the PDF using this data in your application by using a libraries like,

1. js PDF - https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF
2. fPDF - http://www.fpdf.org/
3. TCPDF - https://tcpdf.org/